# How to dismiss the keyboard on a UITextView on a modally presented UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

Good Evening,

I am trying to dismiss a keyboard on a modally presented UITableView.
The `UITextView` is Created as a `UINib` and registered in the `UITableView`.

I tried to set the keyboard as "Dismiss On Drag" in storyboard, and nothing worked. I also wrote the following code and connected the `UITextFieldDelegate` on the `UINib`.

Here is the code in the `UITextView` Nib.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
          if(text == "\n") {
              textView.resignFirstResponder()
              return false
          }
          return true
      }
```

View Did Load:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    textView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: You may need to provide a bit more information about your structure. I just did a quick test: custom cell with a `UITextField` ... `UITableViewController` with `Dismiss on Drag` set on the table view ... presented modally ... tap in a cell's text field to start editing and the keyboard appears ... I then drag down a little on the table view and the keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: It’s not a UITextField, it’s a UITextView.

Comment: I don't see any difference using a `UITextField` or `UITextView` - keyboard is dismissed properly either way ... other than, of course, if I'm scrolling *within* the text view it doesn't dismiss the keyboard (which we wouldn't want). Maybe try to put together a [mre], as it seems something else must be going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use scroll view, this is an example because I don't understand well what do you to do in your project... First set the controller that include your textView to UIScrollViewDelegate, after that declare your objects and their attributes:

```
class YourController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

let scrollView2: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scrollView
}()

let textV: UITextView = {
    let v = UITextView()
    v.backgroundColor = .yourColor
    v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    v.textColor = .white
    v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .regular)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1000).isActive = true // assign here the text view height to allow your scrollview to scroll
    return v
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    scrollView2.delegate = self

    setupConstraints() // call the function for constraints
}
```

below viewDidLoad write constraint function:

```
fileprivate func setupConstraints() {
    
    view.addSubview(scrollView2)
    scrollView2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    scrollView2.addSubview(textV)
    textV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView2.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    textV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView2.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    textV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView2.topAnchor).isActive = true
    textV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView2.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    // this is important for scrolling
    textV.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView2.widthAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

now call scrollViewWillBeginDragging and assign interactive mode to your scrollview keyboardDismissMode:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView2.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
}
```

This is the result

[image]